# What is a good way to implement a queue in vanilla node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, queue

I'm trying to implement a javascript queue, and i would like some pointers or a good library for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think events would be a simple way to do this, however if you are trying to do a queue I think it might be best to use something like [js-queue](https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/js-queue)
It has good documentation and easy to understand examples.

> var Queue=require('js-queue');
>       //create a new queue instance
>       var queue=new Queue;

```
for(var i=0; i<50; i++){
    //add a bunch of stuff to the queue
    queue.add(makeRequest);
}

function makeRequest(){
    //do stuff
    console.log('making some request');

    this.next();
}
```

If you are using this in the browser it will work with browserify and webpack too.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into implementation of the Arrays (check array library) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array, that should be as simple as array.push, array.shift

Comment: btw **This is the first thing you should do** ...